# Find a cubic polynomial with given property.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

**Question.** For a monic, irreducible cubic polynomial $p(x)\in \Bbb Z[x]$ with three real roots, prove or disprove that $p(x^3)$ must be irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ as well.

Here the notation $p(x^3)$ means substituting $x\mapsto x^3$ so we get a degree $9$ monic polynomial. I failed to find counterexamples.

My attempt: Let $\omega$ be a primitive $3^{rd}$ root of unity over $\Bbb Q$ then if the roots of $p(x)$ are $a^3,b^3,c^3$ then the roots of $p(x^3)$ are $a,\omega a, \omega^2a,b,\omega b, \omega^2b,c,\omega c, \omega^2c$.

Comment: Why do you think that the roots will be helpful? In contrast to widespread belief, irreducibility is not connected to roots in any way (there are irreducible polynomials with roots, and there are reducible polynomials with no roots).

Comment: It is worth pointing out that if $p(x)$ satisfies Eisenstein's criterion, then $p(x^3)$ will too. So whatever example you seek should not fall into the class of those satisfying the criterion. But as Martin said, i does not appear clear to me why the additional roots help.